# Webcam does not stop after closing program

Tags: c#, wpf, webcam, aforge

I'm creating wpf application and capturing images with my usb webcam. The library I'm using is Aforge. Everything is fine, I mean I get the live stream from the webcam and I'm able to capture images etc.
But the problem is when I close the program camera is still running (Yellow LED is showing) and the program is not ending. How could I get the camera stopped?

```
protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
{
  base.OnClosing(e);            
  if (WebCam != null)
      if (WebCam.IsRunning)
         {
           WebCam.SignalToStop();
           WebCam.WaitForStop();
           WebCam = null;
          }
}
```

this is how I'm using `NewFreameEventArgs` to get stream

```
 public void Cam_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {            
            try
            {
                System.Drawing.Image img = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
                bi.BeginInit();
                bi.StreamSource = ms;
                bi.EndInit();
                bi.Freeze();

                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(delegate
                {
                    previewWindow.Source = bi;

                    mainCameraImageControl.Source = bi;
                }));

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you should check if you have registered for any event of webcam. If yes, unsubscribe the same.

```
WebCam.NewFrame -= new NewFrameEventHandler(WebCam_NewFrameReceived);
```

**Edit:** Reply to your comments and edited question

```
WebCam.NewFrame -= new NewFrameEventHandler(WebCam_NewFrameReceived);
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
WebCam.SignalToStop();
WebCam.WaitForStop();
```

First, unsubscribe the events. Then call `InvokeShutdown()`. Following is from Microsoft [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invokeshutdown(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The Dispatcher does not shut down completely until the event queue unwinds.

This way, events and dispatchers are disconnected from instance. Then you signal the cam to stop and wait for stop.

Comment: I've update my question. Sorry for asking stupid question but where and how could I shutdown current dispatcher

Answer (score 0):

You're signaling the webcam to stop, but not actually waiting for it to stop.

Your `Webcam` object should have a `WaitToStop()` method, that you should also call after `SignalToStop()`.

Also check [this aforge.net thread](http://www.aforgenet.com/aforge/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2160) for more information.

Comment: I have tried WaitForStop() method as well, but it helps  me partly. I mean some times WebCam stops imediately and some times stop time is hours.

Comment: Definitely check the thread I linked. You may have a multithreading issue, and not using the same Dispatcher to use and stop your webcam. If it helps you, I'll edit the question.